Debian Server goes offline and online in a loop
I'm experiencing network issues with my Debian 12 server (hosting a GitLab instance via Docker) after a recent power outage. The server, running on Hyper-V, changed its IP from 192.168.10.118 to 192.168.10.119. I then set a static IP address (192.168.10.118) in /etc/network/interfaces.
After rebooting, the server goes online for a few minutes before becoming unreachable (including SSH), and then it cycles between online and offline at random intervals (from minutes to hours). However, I can always ping the server at 192.168.10.118 from any machine, but SSH fails when it's "offline."
Interestingly, the server is always accessible via SSH from another server on the same subnet (192.168.10.23).
The server can ping 8.8.8.8 but cannot resolve DNS names (e.g., google.com).
Logs from NetworkManager and UFW seem fine, and stopping Docker doesn't fix the problem.
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.10.118 80          ALLOW       Anywhere
192.168.10.118 22          ALLOW       Anywhere
192.168.10.118 443         ALLOW       Anywhere
192.168.10.118 2424        ALLOW       Anywhere

Here is also my neofetch
$ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          debian
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------------
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: Virtual Machine Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.1
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 7 days, 21 hours, 38 mins
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 1681 (dpkg)
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1024x768
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         Terminal: /dev/pts/1
 `$$b      "-.__              CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2609 v3 (4) @ 1.897GHz
  `Y$$                        Memory: 6496MiB / 16013MiB
   `Y$$.
     `$$b.
       `Y$$b.
          `"Y$b._
              `"""

I’m not sure where else to look for the cause of this intermittent connectivity issue. Any suggestions?
